# Not able to add elements to STL map

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, stl, stdmap

I am writing a text file parser in C++. For that, I have to store "valueToParse"(a string type) and its corresponding regular expression(a string type) in map. I have defined map in .h file and included it in main. While building the solution I am observing error as below:

> error C2057: expected constant expression  c:\mypractice\hobbyprojects\MyParser\logparser.h
>
> error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0   c:\mypractice\hobbyprojects\MyParser\logparser.h
>
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int  c:\mypractice\hobbyprojects\MyParser\logparser.h
>
> error C2040: 'ValuesToParse' : 'int []' differs in levels of indirection from 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' c:\mypractice\hobbyprojects\MyParser\logparser.h
>
> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [4]' to 'int []' c:\mypractice\hobbyprojects\MyParser\logparser.h

and my C++ code is as below:

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include "logParser.h"
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

## logParser.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, std::string> ValuesToParse;
ValuesToParse["FileName"] = "xyz";  
ValuesToParse["Author"] = "abc";
```

## logParser.cpp

```
#include "logParser.h"
```

I googled the errors but no luck. Please don't mind I am new to C++. Could anyone please help me in understanding this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *two* problems:

The first is that you *define* a variable inside the header file. That means it will be defined in each [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) where the header file is included. That's not the source of your *current* problem though.

The second problem, and what's leading to your errors, is that you have general statements outside of a function. Outside a function you can only have *declarations* and *definitions*.

The answer to both these problems would have been in your text book.

Comment: Got your points, thank you.  I am from python background, so the second problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You have code in global scope, you need to put it into a function (logparser.cpp), e.g.:

```
void initialize()
{
  ValuesToParse["FileName"] = "xyz";  
  ValuesToParse["Author"] = "abc";
}
```

then insert the declaration into header file

```
void initialize();
```

and call it within `main()` function